# Show div inside a modal on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an app that display 5 `div` each containing a specific kind of data.

I would like to be able to show one of the `div` in a modal so that the user can see the data in bigger size.

This would be trigger by a button placed in the top right corner.

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui grid">
    <div class="sixteen wide column center aligned">
        <a href="http://www.meteo.be/meteo/view/fr/65239-Accueil.html" target="_blank" class="ui negative basic button">IRM Website</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sixteen wide column center aligned mediumBox"> <!-- DIV 1 -->
        <button class="circular ui tiny icon right floated basic button"><i class="maximize icon"></i></button>
        <map bassins="vm.bassins" dataset="pluviometre" ng-if="vm.bassins"></map>
    </div>
    <div class="four wide column smallBox"> <!-- DIV 2 -->
        <button class="circular ui tiny icon right floated basic button"><i class="maximize icon"></i></button>
        <img />
    </div>
    <div class="four wide column smallBox"> <!-- DIV 3 -->
        <button class="circular ui tiny icon right floated basic button"><i class="maximize icon"></i></button>
        <img />
    </div>
    <div class="four wide column smallBox"> <!-- DIV 4 -->
        <button class="circular ui tiny icon right floated basic button"><i class="maximize icon"></i></button>
        <map bassins="vm.bassins" ng-if="vm.bassins"></map>
    </div>
    <div class="four wide column smallBox"> <!-- DIV 5 -->
        <button class="circular ui tiny icon right floated basic button"><i class="maximize icon"></i></button>
        <map bassins="vm.bassins" ng-if="vm.bassins"></map>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui modal"> <!-- The modal -->
    <i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="header">Data in modal</div>
    <div class="content">
        Here is my content
    </div>
</div>
```

The modal need this javascript to be shown

```
$('.ui.modal').modal('show');
```

The idea is that each button triggers a function inside my controller

```
vm.maximizeData = function(){
    $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
}
```

But how can I display the correct div inside the modal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question says you want to show a data of particular clicked element into the modal dynamically.

- Use a selector to have `parent child` for click function
- Get the content of respective / `closest` / `next` DIV content that you want to show in modal as bigger data.
- Set the modal content and then show it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="mainBox">

<div class="smallBox">
  <button class="buttonAction">Button</button>
  <div class="divContent">Content</div>
</div>

<div class="smallBox">
  <button class="buttonAction">Button</button>
  <div class="divContent">Content</div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="ui modal"> <!-- The modal -->
<i class="close icon"></i>
<div class="header">Data in modal</div>
<div class="content">
    Here is my content
</div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Button click
  $('.mainBox .smallBox .buttonAction').click(function(){
     //Get content near to clicked button
     var contentToSet = $(this).next('.divContent').html();
     //Set the data to be shown in modal
     $('.modal').find('.content').html(contentToSet);
     //Make modal show
     $('.modal').modal('show');
  });
});
```

FYI, This is just an example, you may need to change variable names as per your need.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Button click
  $('.buttonAction').click(function(){
     //Get content near to clicked button
     var contentToSet = $(this).next('div.divContent').html();
     console.log(contentToSet);
     //Set the data to be shown in modal
     $('.modal').find('.content').html(contentToSet);
     //Make modal show
     //$('.modal').modal('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainBox">

<div class="smallBox">
  <button class="buttonAction">Button</button>
  <div class="divContent">Content1</div>
</div>

<div class="smallBox">
  <button class="buttonAction">Button</button>
  <div class="divContent">Content2</div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="ui modal"> <!-- The modal -->
<i class="close icon"></i>
<div class="header">Data in modal</div>
<div class="content">
    Here is my content
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using proper selectors as I am ? it should be working.

Comment: I just tried your code inside a code snippet and it does not work

Comment: This is close to what I am trying to do. I have some problem due to my directive that generates a SVG but that's another problem. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Weedoze No problem, Glad to help